# How to iterate till the length of an object array?

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I am using "delnames" object array to create these zoo items and in another method I want to delete them. Creating requires separate method for each but deletion doesn't , just clicking on delete would do. So I want to iterate it on the same dataprovider object array.
here is what I am trying to achieve ; I am using java to write my scripts on ubuntu.

```
@DataProvider(name = "delnames")
    public Object[][] dnames() {
        return new Object[][] { { "zoo" }, { "owl" }, { "lion"}, 
                      { "Peacock" }, { "Chimp" }, { "Fish" }, {"Duck"} };
    }

@Test(dataProvider = "delnames")
public void delete(String name1){
for (lenth of dnames){ ================ >> HOW ?????
driver.findElement(By.linkText("delete"));
syso(name1+" is deleted");
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried googling for "iteration array java" or "for loop array java" or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an ArrayList or Vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dnames.size(); i++) {
    ...
}
```

If it is an array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dnames.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @jampI have already tried what you gave me. I tried **for (int i = 0; i < dnames().length; i++) <br/>{<br/>}** , but it only fetches first item in the array. I want to delete all these 7 items in the array with the help of array.

Comment: do you want to delete the array itself  or empty the array?

Comment: not the array :). The item from my application. I have created few items now I have to delete them, to see this in console, I am putting a sys out saying that "item is deleted". deletion of items goes just after the creation, so I want to use same array twice. first I am using for creation and then for deletion.

Comment: As Aromal Sasidharan said... I don't see why u are using a 2-dimensional array here... and the code is really messy... why would u print "xxx is deleted" as many times as the number of elements in the array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use choose one dimensional array,  instead of two dimensional array.

```
Object dnames [] = new Object[]{"owl","zoo","Chimp","Fish","Duck"};
```

we can loop through one dimensional array as follows

```
for(Object item: dnames)
{
System.out.println(item); // do your stuff here with item  
}
```

Comment: What we can do it iterate a two dimensional array? We need to delete and then print " 'item' + " deleted" , for each item of that array in my question?

Comment: @Cedric , I tried your way and changed to one dimensional array, and applied the loop that you gave me. But it gives error(red groovy line) under dnames saying "Change type of params to object" , and when I do so , it gives red line under params in second line saying Can only iterate over and instance of array or an instance of java.lang.iterable.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test(dataProvider = "delnames")
public void delete(String name1){
  for (Object[] params : dnames()) {
    for (Object o : params) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, you don't want to do this in your test method since `dnames()` is its data provider, but I'm assuming you're just showing this as an example.

Comment: I tried your way and changed to one dimensional array, and applied the loop that you gave me. But it gives error(red groovy line) under dnames saying "Change type of params to object" , and when I do so , it gives red line under params in second line saying Can only iterate over and instance of array or an instance of java.lang.iterable